# Verifying AzureAD access token with Django-REST-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, azure-active-directory, django-rest-auth

Before anything I would like to warn you about my extremely limited knowledge on the subject.
Now that you've been warned, what I need to ask is how can I verify and azureAD access token with Django/django-rest-framework.

I have a app that I need to sign in to with azureAD, which means I need to get an access token from azureAD, and thankfully this is will be done on the frontend side with Angular what I need to do is verify that token on the backend side with django/django-rest-framework and I have no idea where to start from, can anyone suggest a way to do this or send me in the right direction ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I owe this to my past self.

What I did is got the authorization from the headers of the request, sliced it so it's the token only and used the used the microsoft keys url, audience and jwt package to decode it, here is the code:

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/5c9b264f-33ad-4093-bb65-8d14aaec9f63/discovery/v2.0/keys"
valid_audience = 'api://0d44e6da-8e5b-4e98-94b5-5f02ce228647'

response = urlopen(url)
jwks = json.loads(response.read())


def is_logged_in(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        token = self.headers['Authorization'][7:]  # Need to test this against the frontend request.
        try:
            jwks_client = PyJWKClient(url)
            signing_key = jwks_client.get_signing_key_from_jwt(token)

            decoded = jwt.decode(token,
                             signing_key.key,
                             algorithms=["RS256"],
                             audience=valid_audience)

            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)

    wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__
    return wrapper
```

Also I put it all in a in a decorator so I can hide all my apis behind it.